# Ant Design Select dropdown list aria label accessibility

Tags: antd, wai-aria

I am trying to implement accessibility for my dropdown list. I used antd's Select component. But my problem is that when I use keyboard up and down arrow keys to navigate in the listbox(dropdown list), the computer does not read aria label that I passed in to the  out, actually I can't even pass aria label and tabIndex into Option.  Do you have any idea how I can fix this problem?

```
<Select
    showSearch
    style={{ width: 200 }}
    placeholder="Select a person"
    optionFilterProp="children"
    onChange={onChange}
    onFocus={onFocus}
    onBlur={onBlur}
    onSearch={onSearch}
    filterOption={(input, option) =>
      option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
    }
  >
    <div aria-label={"jack"} tabIndex={0}><Option aria-label={"jack"} tabIndex={0} value="jack">Jack</Option>
    <Select.Option aria-label={"lucy"} tabIndex={0} value="lucy">
      Lucy
    </Select.Option>
    <Select.Option aria-label={"tom"} tabIndex={0} value="tom">
      Tom
    </Select.Option>
  </Select>
```

Thanks

Comment: I also want to know.

Comment: Could you tell us which browser(s) and screen reader(s) you're using to test?

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding, but it seems to me that your solution works. I reproduced your component at the following [CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-combobox-option-with-aria-label-lrxi9).

You can inspect the dropdown list and the `aria-label`s are indeed present (see dev tools pic below) and on my Mac VoiceOver does speak the names of each of the menu items.

[image]